# Google Drive root location

Tags: directory, root, google-drive-api

I want to place my Google Drive folder in root directory C:\

So I want to have location C:\Google Drive\

How can I configure it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's actually quite easy

1. Go into your Google Drive and choose Quit your Google drive
2. Now relocate your Google Drive to whereever you like.
3. Now start your Drive program again.
4. You will get an error that Drive cannot locate your folder.
5. Click on the Error Message
6. Click on Locate Folder, and locate your Drive folder to the new
   location, the location you have moved your drive to.

and off you go!

Comment: @Pepe I have answered your question. even though the question is closed you can still upvote/accept my answer.